# How to select multiple columns in power Bi using slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as88e.jpg)I have a table with the following column headers:
Row ID, Order Priority, Discount,   Unit Price, Shipping Cost,  Customer ID,    Customer Name,  Ship Mode,  Customer Segment,   Product Category,   Product Sub-Category,   Product Container,  Product Name,   Product Base Margin, Country,   Region, State,  Province,   City,   Postal Code,    Order Date, Ship Date,  Profit, Quantity ordered,new    Sales,  Order ID

I want to filter some columns from this table by clicking on a slicer. Examples:

If I select 1.5 in my slicer, I should see the following columns: Row ID,   Order Priority, Discount,   Unit Price, Shipping Cost,  Customer ID,    Customer Name,  Ship Mode,  Customer Segment,   Product Category,   Product Sub-Category

If I select 2.5 in my slicer, I should see the following columns: Row ID,   Product, Sub-Category,  Product Container,  Product Name,   Product Base, Margin,   Country Region
If I select 3.5 in my slicer, I should see the following columns: Product Category, Product Sub-Category,   Product Container,  Product Name,   Product Base Margin,    Country,    Region, State,      Postal Code,    Order Date, Ship Date,  Profit

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, I'm assuming you mean show/hide columns in a visual and not actually to filter those columns.

For Table visuals, it is not possible to show/hide columns. And for Matrix visuals, you can only show/hide value (measures) columns.

For your scenario, I would suggest you create three versions of the visual with the desired columns, then use Bookmarks together with the Bookmark navigator, to show one and hide the other two.

See [How To Show & Hide Visuals Using Power BI Bookmarks](https://www.overbeeps.com/show-hide-visuals-power-bi-bookmarks-button/) and [Bookmark navigator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/button-navigators?tabs=powerbi-desktop#bookmark-navigator).